# How to install android sdks manually for meteor

Tags: android, node.js, meteor

I have really poor internet connection. Is there any way that i could download it form google server and install the sdks for android manually? I tried many times from

`meteor install-sdk android` command, but my poor network gets in the way.

How do i download and configue the sdks for android manually for Meteor mobile?

Answer (score 1):

From the [wiki](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/wiki/Meteor-Cordova-Phonegap-integration):

```
env USE_GLOBAL_ADK=t meteor run android    # will run android and adb from global PATH
```

So you can install an ADK at your own leisure and make Meteor use it.